# Numpy multiple masks with conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Goal:
Given an `int` numpy array, `x` of shape `d x 1`, where the contents of the array are random indices. The range of `x` is from `(0, n)`, where n is the max possible index. (`n << len(x)`). My goal is to get the indices that correspond to each index.

For eg:

```
n = 3
x = [2, 0, 3, 3, 2]
out = required_fn(x, n)
# out should be [[1], [], [0, 4], [2,3]].
# i.e. for 0, it is at index 1, for 1, there is no occurence, for 2,it occurs at indices 0, 4
```

I'm looking for the most efficient implementation that can help me with this. This would be used in a data loader, so efficiency is important.

I tried a stupid attempt by:

```
x[x == np.array(list(range(n))]
```

But this obviously did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`numpy`'s `argwhere` was designed for this:

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
x = np.array([2, 0, 3, 3, 2])
res = []
for i in range(n+1):
    res.append( np.argwhere(x==i).tolist()) 

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[[1]], [], [[0], [4]], [[2], [3]]]
```

Comment: This is not a good use of `argwhere`, the complexity is `O(n²)`. If you must loop, use pure python ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since your output is not a valid (non-object) numpy array, a `O(n)` approach would be a simple loop.

```
n = 3
x = [2, 0, 3, 3, 2]

d = {k: [] for k in range(n+1)}
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    d[v].append(i)
    
out = list(d.values())
```

Output:

```
[[1], [], [0, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `where`

```
[list(*np.where(x==i)) for i in range(n+1)]
```

which gives

```
[[1], [], [0, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: The complexity is `O(n²)`, you can have `O(n)` with a simple loop.

Comment: @mozway aha, that’s true, and your solution looks better in terms of efficiency, upvoted yours already, cheers!

Comment: I guess for very small small `n`, `where` might not be that bad (there's sometimes a region in which inefficient numpy can be faster than efficient python). If `k<<n` then the complexity is only `O(k*n)` ;)